# Android Storage Access FrameWork with custom file system

Tags: android, usb

I'm using android Storage Access Framework API to access an external mass storage usb drive plugged into android.

My questions is, what if the usb drive contains a file format is not understood by android, will I still be able to access the files on the external USB drive?

Will i be able to write my own low level functions to access a drive whose file format is not known to android Storage Access FrameWork?

Lets say i create my own drive format for security reasons, how will Android present the dialog box showing the user the files contents so they can pick a file granting the app permission to access that file it it doesnt know the file format of the drive?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> what if the usb drive contains a file format is not understood by android, will I still be able to access the files on the external USB drive?

Yep.

> Will i be able to write my own low level functions to access a drive whose file format is not known to android Storage Access FrameWork?

You'll have to write your own USB drivers using the low level [USB APIs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html) (as you said, Android doesn't know how to read your USB drive)

> Lets say i create my own drive format for security reasons, how will Android present the dialog box showing the user the files contents so they can pick a file granting the app permission to access that file it it doesnt know the file format of the drive?

Nothing in the [DocumentsProvider API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsProvider.html) controls how your files are read from disk (if they even are read from disk - in many cases, like with the Google Drive DocumentsProvider, they are read from a remote server). As long as fulfill the API by returning a `Cursor` for the root from [queryRoots()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsProvider.html#queryRoots(java.lang.String[])), a `Cursor` with the proper fields from [queryDocument()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsProvider.html#queryDocument(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) for a single document and a `Cursor` with a list of documents from [queryChildDocuments()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsProvider.html#queryChildDocuments(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String)), then the Storage Access Framework will list your files correctly.

Just make sure you provide a valid `ParcelFileDescriptor` to [openDocument()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsProvider.html#openDocument(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.CancellationSignal)) which would allow read/write access to your custom file format system.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers and your help. But you are saying that android 6.0.1 and Storage Access FrameWork allows apps to write their own low level USB (builk transfer etc) to access the usb drive plugged into the android directly? I thought low level USB functions were blocked and we only can use the storage access framework to get a uri to the usb document and everything is accessed through the uri?

Comment: I thought in order to access a file on the USB drive plugged into android, first the android OS will display a dialog box (on its own) to the user, when the user picks a file, then the android OS grants access to that file only to the app. So if the Android OS cant read the file names from the USB drive (maybe because the whole USB drive has been encrypted), then how will it present the file names to the user? Maybe i didnt read it right, but what you say does make sense, but I'm really new to all this.

Comment: You've picked an area where almost no developer ever goes and there's little documentation or support. The whole point of Storage Access Framework is to abstract *any* device or file storage. The framework itself uses this to provide access to SD cards and attached USB storage devices (as there is no direct File access to those locations). That's totally separate from you providing your own drivers for a custom USB device.

Comment: ianhanniballake - thanks so much for your comments, are you saying Android allows us to write our own low level USB code to access maybe a drive with a custom format (or encrypted)? I thought they block all that and the only way to do it is to use a rooted Android? How do I write a Android driver, i thought all app code in android was application level?

Comment: we are making a commercial application, so we cant require customers to root their android phones in order to use our app.